# Continuous location tracking and generating local notification even after termination of application in ios (Flutter)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, location, geofencing

I am developing a flutter app to do geofencing and generating local notifications even when the app is in background or terminated. I use background_services, flutter_local_notification, geolocator packages to achieve this on android. But I don't know the way to do this in ios and i don't even know whether it is possible in ios. I must do this periodically for every 30 min or 1 hour.

Is there any way of achieving this (keep tracking the location of user and generate if the user is near the pre-define location) on ios in flutter or any native language (swift/C++) and connecting this with flutter app?

Comment: iOS has in-built geofencing capability - You need "Always" location permission.  [This plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/geofence_service) might help.  You can't check every time period, but you don't need to - Just define the region you want to monitor and you will get a callback when the device enters or exits the region.